# Multiple index entry

Tags: indexing

I want to know what is the proper way to do multiple indexes in languages where the adjectives come after the subject. For example in english if I want to index the inverse function I can do:

```
\index{function!inverse}
\index{inverse function}
```

In spanish, for example, it could be:

```
\index{función!inversa}
\index{inversa}
\index{inversa@función inversa}
\index{inversa@(función) inversa}
\index{inversa@función inversa}
\index{inversa@función inversa}
\index{inversa|see{función}}
\index{inversa|seealso{función}}
```

I don't want to use the `see` and `seealso` ways. How is this usually done?

Comment: What do you want the index entries to look like? Your question is quite unclear to me!

Comment: I want to do something like the english version \index{inverse function} but I don't know how to do it. I haven't seen any book which does that.

Comment: `\index{inversa@función inversa}` doesn't make much sense to me. I'd go with `\index{función!inversa}` and maybe`\index{inversa!función inversa}` if you also have other instances of `\index{inversa}`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference: you list the entries according to the main term, in this case *función*.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\section{Función}

\index{integral}
\index{série}
\index{cálculo}

\index{función}
\index{función!inversa}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to choose one primary format, probably `\index{function!inverse}`; for all the other formats, you just use `\index{inverse function|see {function!inverse}}` once anywhere in the document.